# how to bind-mount data directory in windows container

Tags: mysql, docker

I am deploying a mysql server in windows container. When bind-mount the data directoy of mysql, I encounter some error.

the docker information as follows:

```
    Containers: 2
     Running: 0
     Paused: 0
     Stopped: 2
    Images: 15
    Server Version: 18.09.2
    Storage Driver: lcow (linux) windowsfilter (windows)
     LCOW:
     Windows:
    Logging Driver: json-file
    Plugins:
     Volume: local
     Network: ics l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent
     Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gelf json-file local logentries splunk syslog
    Swarm: inactive
    Default Isolation: hyperv
    Kernel Version: 10.0 17134 (17134.1.amd64fre.rs4_release.180410-1804)
    Operating System: Windows 10 Pro Version 1803 (OS Build 17134.472)
    OSType: windows
    Architecture: x86_64
    CPUs: 4
    Total Memory: 7.927GiB
    Name: 1512010NB01
    ID: CX5Q:ZLPK:H23T:KKXB:7P5I:7JY3:R5RO:CKFL:3ZRT:KNZ5:AJGW:V35W
    Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\Docker
    Debug Mode (client): false
    Debug Mode (server): true
     File Descriptors: -1
     Goroutines: 30
     System Time: 2019-06-26T11:11:55.1161658+08:00
     EventsListeners: 1
    Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
    Labels:
    Experimental: true
    Insecure Registries:
     127.0.0.0/8
    Live Restore Enabled: false
    Product License: Community Engine
```

the docker version as follows:

```
    Client: Docker Engine - Community
     Version:           18.09.2
     API version:       1.39
     Go version:        go1.10.8
     Git commit:        6247962
     Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:12:31 2019
     OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
     Experimental:      false

    Server: Docker Engine - Community
     Engine:
      Version:          18.09.2
      API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.24)
      Go version:       go1.10.6
      Git commit:       6247962
      Built:            Sun Feb 10 04:28:48 2019
      OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
      Experimental:     true
```

bellow is my docker file

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:1803

LABEL Author="aa@bb.cc.dd" MySQLVersion="8.0.13"

RUN powershell -Command \
    Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/A/A/6AA4EDFF-645B-48C5-81CC-ED5963AEAD48/vc_redist.x64.exe" -OutFile "C:\vc_redist.x64.exe"; \
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol='tls12,tls11,tls'; \
    Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-8.0/mysql-8.0.13-winx64.zip" -OutFile "C:\MySQL.zip"; \
    && vc_redist.x64.exe  /install /passive /norestart /quiet \
    && powershell -command \
    Expand-Archive -Path c:\mysql.zip -DestinationPath C:\ ; \
    ren C:\mysql-8.0.13-winx64 C:\MySQL ; \
    Remove-Item c:\MySQL.zip -Force; \
    Remove-Item c:\vc_redist.x64.exe; \
    && powershell -f InitMySql.ps1 \
    && powershell -command Remove-Item c:\InitMySql.ps1 -Force; \
    && setx PATH /M %PATH%;C:\MySQL\bin

EXPOSE 3306/tcp
ENTRYPOINT ["powershell.exe", "C:\\MySQL\\bin\\mysqld.exe", "--console"]
```

After building the image and executing

> docker run -it --name testmysql --mount type=bind,src=c:\backup,dst=C:\MySQL\data  xxxx/mysqlforwindows:latest

some error happen as follows:

> [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\MySQL\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.13) starting as process 1324 
>   [ERROR] [MY-011011] [Server] Failed to find valid data directory. 
>   [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed. 
>   [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting 
>   [System][MY-010910] [Server] C:\MySQL\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.13)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

There are some suggestions in mysql document, the error may result from the socket file, but I don't how to fix it.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/8.0/en/deploy-mysql-nonlinux-docker.html

how to resolve the problem, does anyone have suggestion? thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to build your image but getting this error `1803: Pulling from microsoft/windowsservercore : no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries`. Are you facing the same issue, how you overcome it.

Comment: did you already configured a shared directory ?

Comment: I have encountered the same issue as yours. but I forget  the reason. maybe the reason is that the windows core version of your host isn't 1803, or the docker shourd switch to windows container, not linux container. thanks.